# переход по страницам с помощью стрелок на клавиатуре ПК

Tags: jquery

На странице постраничной навигации имеются две кнопки, которые листают страницы по одной, назад и вперед.

```
<a id="prev" class="page" href="?page=9">9</a>  7  8  9  "10"  11  12  13  <a id="next" class="page" href="?page=11">11</a>
```

Подскажите как можно заставить браузер перейти по `id="prev"` нажимая `"стрелку влево"` на клавиатуре и `id="next"` нажимая `"стрелку вправо"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { 
    // лево
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { 
     // право
  }
});
```